# How do we refer people to the site?

Tags: support, site-promotion

How do we send referrals out for the Worldbuilding site?  I know a few people who might be interested but I'm not seeing anyplace that gives me a referral link.  I ask because I've noticed others have 'credit' for referring on Area 51.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only get "credit" for referring people pre-private beta. But you can refer anyone to the site now, especially once it has entered public beta. Once it has entered public beta, just send them the link.

Right now you can invite specific people by email to the private beta. Go to the main site, and look on the right hand sidebar. There is a box that says "Invite Fellow Experts." Fill in the data to invite someone.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was wondering if it was something like that.  I'll just wait until it goes public beta then.  It's an internet group and I don't have all their emails.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, it won't be too long till we hit public beta.